# Grid to many planes?

Tags: python

I need a lot of independent planes (like 200x300), but creating them programmatically with a loop took a lot of time (with `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane()` or with vertices and faces). But creating one grid with subdivisions is very cheap. My problem is, that the vertices of the subdivision planes are connected and i need them independent (having each inner vertice four times).

So i would ask you, if there is an option to divide an grid in many independent planes?

Comment: @UlfAslak this is using a script not the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the edge split operator to divide the grid into individual squares , then you can separate them by loose parts , here is the lines that do that :

```
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'SELECT')        
        bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
        bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type = 'LOOSE')
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Comment: this works pretty good on small amounts (20x30), but if i use it on 200x300 blender freezes also. is there a solution for it? thanks a lot

Comment: I have tested this in the UI (no script) and blender is still frozen while i'm writing, so I suggest that you create small grid ( 10x10) separate this parts then loop over them  subdivide each (20x30) and separate ( when you separate the planes will be selected so just loop through selected_object )

Comment: can i divide a plane to a grid?

Comment: @vtni  `mesh.subdivide(number_cuts = 10)`

Comment: i have one last question: how can i get all separated planes in a list, to iterate over them (and split again)?

Comment: @vtni  `list = context.selected_objects.copy()`  then loop in this list , it want change with the selection because it is a separate copy

Comment: unfortunately with this method the whole computer freezes. i think i have to take a look at Modals.